# My view isn't returning dropdownlist information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am running the Visual studio 2012 debugger, and have found that my productViewModelList parameter does not contain all the values I want my view to pass to my [HTTPPOST] Edit action.  I don't understand why.  Please refer to the comment in the code sample below for the location I that I inserted the breakpoint and checked the values of productViewModelList.

The following values are given to productViewModelList:

> BrandId = 0,
>   BrandName = "6",
>   BrandSelectListItem = null,
>   ID = 5,
>   Name = "Crutch",
>   Price = 10.0

- BrandID is incorrect, In the view in my DropDownList, I assign "Catatonics Inc." Which has an ID of 6, Which I verified in my database.
- BrandName is showing "6" which should be in BrandID, BrandName should be "Catatonics Inc."
- BrandSelectList item is an object of type SelectListItem, it contains the values that go into The DropDownList item in my view. The DropDownList correctly shows the values, but BrandSelectList is `null` when my [httpPost] edit action executes.  I need to access the DropDownList's Selected item.
- all other values, ID, Name, and Price are correct.

Here are some classes in my code.

### MedicalProductController

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb();

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> productViewModelList)
    {
        // I have a breakpoint inserted here, and check productViewModelList with debugger.  

        var modelList = GetMedicalProductList(productViewModelList);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var model in modelList)
                _db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(productViewModelList);
    }
}
```

### MedicalProductMapper

```
public class MedicalProductMapper
{

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> MapMedicalProductViewModel(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        var brandSelectListItem = brandList.Select(b => new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = b.Name,
                                                    Value = b.ID.ToString()
                                                });

        var viewModelList = productList.Select(p => new MedicalProductViewModel() 
                                {
                                    BrandID = p.BrandID,
                                    BrandName = brandList.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == p.BrandID).Name,
                                    BrandSelectListItem = brandSelectListItem,
                                    ID = p.ID,
                                    Price = p.Price,
                                    Name = p.Name
                                });

        return viewModelList;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> MapMedicalProductList(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> viewModelList)
    {
        var modelList = viewModelList.ToArray().Select( viewModel => new MedicalProduct()
        {
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Price = viewModel.Price,
            BrandID = Convert.ToInt32(viewModel.BrandSelectListItem.Select(b => b.Value.ToString()))
        });

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

### EDIT.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m)        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

### EditorTemplates/MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml

(this is in subdirectory of Edit.cshtml's directory.)

```
@model MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.ID)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.BrandName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandName, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.BrandName)
</div>
```

## EDIT:

### Brand

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### MedicalProduct

```
public class MedicalProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // is a foreign key
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
}
```

### MedicalProductViewModel

```
public class MedicalProductViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public int BrandID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="[Generic]")]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandSelectListItem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it could be that your parameter name doesn't match up with what is being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a form element for `BrandID`, so when the model binder translates the form POST into a model it's going to use the default value for `int`, which is 0.  You *do* have a form element for `BrandName`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandName, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
```

This is presumably (depending on the definition of `BrandSelectListItem`, and based on the observed behavior you describe) going to create a `select` element where the `option` elements use the available `BrandName` values as the text and the available `BrandID` values as the value.  When a `select` element is included in an HTTP POST, the selected value is what is posted.  So you're getting the selected `BrandID`, but assigning it to the value for `BrandName` by binding it to that property on the model.

It sounds like what you *really* want is this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandID, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
```

This would then give you:

```
BrandId = 6, BrandName = "", BrandSelectListItem = null, ID = 5, Name = "Crutch", Price = 10.0
```

You still don't have a `BrandName` value, but do you really need one in this case?  It's duplicated data.  The model can dynamically determine the `BrandName` from the known `BrandID`.  So `BrandName` doesn't need to be a read/write property on the model, it can just be a read-only property which fetches the `BrandName` based on the model's `BrandID`.  It might be something as simple as:

```
public string BrandName
{
    get
    {
        var brandName = GetBrandName(BrandID);
        return brandName;
    }
}
```

In this case you'd implement `GetBrandName` to fetch the value from the data store.  Or do the whole thing in-line if it's clear and concise enough, that's up to you.  You could also cache the value in a class-level private variable so that it only needs to be fetched once.  (Just make sure to clear out that variable or re-fetch it any time `BrandID` changes.)

You *could* keep both properties as they are, but then you'd be responsible for making sure they stay synchronized for the life of the object, which includes the time it spends in the UI.  Any time you have the same piece of information recorded in two places, you have the responsibility of keeping it synchronized.  Which is never fun.  In this case you'd need two elements in the view (the second one could be a hidden form field, or perhaps a drop down list styled to be hidden), and you'd have to write some JavaScript to update one any time the other one changes.

Comment: I've added some model classes to my question in an edit if that clears anything up.

Comment: @ArmorCode: It doesn't change the fact that your form doesn't have an element named `BrandID` and, therefore, doesn't have a value to supply to the `BrandID` property in the view model.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how I'd implement a GetBrandName function to fetch the BrandName from the data store.  My understanding is that Model classes should only have properties in them, and no methods.

Comment: @ArmorCode: That understanding is not correct at all.  The models should encapsulate as much of the logic and behavior of the system as possible.  Though in this case all you're really adding is a read-only property, which internally gets the data from the data store.  It doesn't need to be in a separate method, that was just for the sake of an example.

Comment: Ok, since the Name property of the Brand model class is not accessible from MedicalProduct, how do I access it?  Create an instance of my DbContext class in the get accessor?

Comment: @ArmorCode: If the DbContext hasn't been abstracted behind any repository or factory or anything like that, then I imagine so yes. Logically speaking I imagine that a `MedicalProduct` object would have a `Brand` property. That property could be populated in any number of ways. Maybe the constructor for `MedicalProduct` could require a `BrandID` and internally convert that to a `Brand`, or just store it in a private field and fetch a `Brand` based on that identifier the first time the `Brand` property is accessed. Or maybe there's an exposed `BrandID` property instead of a constructor argument.

Comment: We were talking about putting the property in the MedicalProduct, but it seems more useful in MedicalProductViewModel.  I can't say "Model.BrandName" in the view, if the Brandname is a property of MedicalProduct, and not MedicalProductViewModel, right?